# ngfor angular2 get contnet from server base on iteration vlaue

Tags: angular

I am looping on array of objects

here is the html for loop

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 box" *ngFor="let partner of foundPartners" >
    <div class="alert">go to webservice for each item in the loop and write alerts here base on the id</div>
</div>
```

now on each loop I need to get the id of the item and then go to the webservice api and get some data base on the item and print it inside the doom.

I used to work with asp.net repeater, there you have ItemDataBound event that can get the item and then make some changes to the doom base on it.

is there something similar in angular2? how can I pull data from api base on the item in the loop and write it to the doom?

Answer (score 0):

You can create own Pipe for it:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 box" *ngFor="let partner of foundPartners" >
<div class="alert"><div *ngFor="let partnerData of (partner?.id | fetch) ">
{{partnerData}}
</div></div>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#an-impure-caching-pipe

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop an array and get data from some api for every item in component. In this case you create array with all necessary information and simply show it in template